# Sales Force UTC time conversion in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, salesforce

Time returned from salesforce is in this format `2017-07-14T12:02:23.000+0000` But I want to convert my saved time that is updated_At `Wed, 04 Oct 2017 23:00:45 PDT -07:00`
 I tries to convert it in utc with time_var.utc but it returned `2017-10-05 06:00:45 UTC`
 
How can i get the  time in salesforce Format `2017-07-14T12:02:23.000+0000`

Comment: you might get better help posting on the dedicated StackExchange: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: i am trying to convert in Ruby on rails. Salesforce time format will not be changed/ or we have to follow the same format

Comment: Please, add your code to question, it will help to understand what's wrong

Comment: What's wrong with `2017-10-05 06:00:45 UTC`?

Comment: salesforce query won't compare it with CreatedDate return with message valid datatime value required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time_in_utc =  DateTime.parse product.updated_at.utc.to_s
last_update_time = time_in_utc.iso8601`

Answer (score 1):

```
updated_at = "Wed, 04 Oct 2017 23:00:45:032 PDT -07:00"
Time.parse(updated_at).utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%T.%L%z")
```